# I'm trying to use pip to install nltk and I'm not necessarily getting an error but I'm also not sure what it means

Tags: python

So I'm running the command to install nltk and i keep on getting the following messages. The requirements are satisfied, but is i attempt to import nltk on my script it doesn't work.

```
-MBP-2 ~ % pip install --user -U nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: regex in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nltk) (2020.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tqdm in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nltk) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: click in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nltk) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nltk) (0.17.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is installed, but in a non-default location so python doesn't find it.

First you should find out where it is located (it looks like `./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`) and then you can extend the path.
There are 2 ways for it either extend the Variable `PYTHONPATH`:

```
# assuming you're on *nix
export PYTHONPATH=~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

# for a permanent fix place it in your .bashrc
echo "export PYTHONPATH=~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> .bashrc
```

Or extend the path in the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
import nltk
```

If you want to check your current path you can use:
`python -c 'import sys; print (sys.path)'`

Comment: Thank you, I realized it was already installed along with a bunch of packages included in Anaconda, but I didn't know what to do about it. I also realize I should have mentioned I'm on Mac OS. Ultimately I found a different command from the documentation and it worked.